# Value of pointer to stack integer (becomes NULL)?

Tags: c++, pointers, null-pointer

Given the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int *pPointer;

int func()
{
    int num;
    num = 25;
    pPointer = &num;
}

int main()
{
    func();
    cout << *pPointer << endl;
    cout << *pPointer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me if I duplicate the following line:

```
cout << *pPointer << endl;
cout << *pPointer << endl;
```

Why I receive 25 (as expected) but then the next value is 0 (NULL)?

Wouldn't the value of int=25 still remain on the stack? What is it about cout that changes the value of pPointer? Am I missing something about my understanding about scope and the stack? (I'm a Java guy, so this was surprising).

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior everywhere. `func()` needs to return an `int`. And dereferencing the pointer after `func()` exits is also undefined.

Comment: The explanation in @GSerg 's link is the best answer.

Comment: Thank you *everyone* I wish I could mark you all as answers. I knew it had to do something with scope and undefined behavior, but thank you for the clarification. Code on!

Comment: Praetorian -- I see that now, yikes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `pPointer` is pointing to a local variable in `func()`.  This area of memory is only valid inside of the `func()` method.  After `func()` exits, the memory that `pPointer` points to is free to be re-used, and appears to be used by `cout`.

If you want to persist this memory, you should either save it by value, or allocate the memory dynamically `pPointer = new int(num)`

Answer (score 2):

`num` does not exist once the function `func()` terminates.

You take its address when it exists, then attempt to print the value at an address that is no longer valid.

Anything can happen.

Comment: ah so at the time I cout the num (via the dereferenced pointer), I have 25, but since func() has already terminated, the next invocation of cout prints a pointer that is undefined? or null depending upon the compiler's implementation? thank you for your insight.

Comment: Both the first and the second time access an address that is no longer valid. Why the value is different on both accesses is anybody's guess (I'll guess the library code for `printf()` clobbered the value there).

Answer (score 1):

As it is undefined behavior, there is no `num` outside of `func` scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << *pPointer << endl;
```

here `*pPointer` is pointing to a local variable of some other function which already returned so the address to which it is pointing is out of scope so the behaviour is `undefined`. it may print the right value assigned to `num` or may not.

Answer (score 0):

> Why I receive 25 (as expected) but then the next value is 0 (NULL)?

What you mention as expected is actually not expected!

`num` becomes out-of-scope as soon as `func()` returns. Although `pPointer` is valid (as it is global),  `*pPointer` is not, because it is pointing to a out-of-scope memory.